# Can we restart a SQL Server instance remotely?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-administration

I am connecting to SQL server 2008 R2 from a remote machine, but when i right click on the instance in object explorer it shows me `Start,Restart,Stop, Pause, Resume` options disabled

I am connecting to default instance on server "DEXTER" [ip: 192.168.1.2] from machine "SPARTAN" [192.168.1.10] in the same network

Comment: you probably familiar that upper case means shouting on the web right?

Comment: sorry i didnt realize. r u talking about the servername or the question?

Comment: The title of your question before you edited...

Answer (score 2):

This means that the user you are currently logged in as does not have the SQL server "sysadmin" server role, and/or has not been granted the server-wide GRANT option "CONTROL SERVER".

One of these is required to control the MSSQL process.

Comment: I realize this is an old post, but I'm trying to get this to work with SQL 2008 R2.  I'm connecting remotely with my Windows account and I am a sysadmin, but my `start, restart, stop, etc` options are disabled when I right click on the instance from Management Studio.  I had to change the instance to "Mixed Mode" auth, but I can't seem to restart it.  Any ideas?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you logged as Sql Server user and have the sysadmin rights - then you can stop the instance by `SHUTDOWN` command. But you can only start the instance if you have such rights on host where sql server resides.

Answer (score -4):

If all options are disabled, SQL has stuck in some process and can not be restarted easily. If there is no sensitive data - try killing SQL processes and then start it again.

Comment: Um.. no, SQL server will not be aware of such a problem until you actually try to stop or restart it. If all options are disabled *before* trying to perform these actions, you lack permission.

Comment: -1 This is just not right and a dangerous practice.  There are plenty of things to look at to determine whether or not SQL is stuck somewhere, which rarely happens anyway.  Management Studio menu options being grayed out should never be cause to think that SQL is dead.  This problem, as mentioned by Oleg Dok and adaptr, is a permissions issue.

Comment: The most likely cause for the service control options of the SQL server management studio to be greyed is NOT that the service is crashed or locked. In fact, it's pretty damned unlikely. The most likely cause is that the user do not have the necessary system-level access to the server to control the service.